# Django.core.validators MinMaxValueValidator ignored from shell

Tags: python, django, custom-validators

I'm using django 1.10, created

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class B(models.Model):
    address = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(63)], blank=True, null=True)
```

when I get in shell_plus and do:

```
x=B()
x.address='1973'
x.save()
```

the row has been recorded. Triyng the same from admin web interface the form give an error, why the shell allow to save the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.

From the [docs for How validators are run](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run)

> ...Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form....